# Geopoint to address

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to know how to transfer geopoint to address Example

```
double src_lat =30.022584 ;
        double src_long = 31.343822;
   srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),(int) (src_long * 1E6));
```

how can i get the address of this srcGeoPoint

Comment: `address`... as in street address?

Comment: address or it's position on the map like "California city" something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    srcGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    srcGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                String add = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                         i++)
                       add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

taken from: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

see geocoding and reverse geocoding about halfway down the page

you might also want to look at  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/