# Android Dev - Get Geo Locations of a PostCode

Tags: android

I am new to Android App development and was hoping I could find some help. I am trying to write an app, which let's me know when I reach a certain given postcode. Thanks to a few examples over the internet, I have managed to find a way to get to Lat/Long (using emulator), but still do not know how I can use it to check if I have reached a certain postcode.

Is there any help regarding this, a link which explains how it can be done.

Please, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: always search before posting, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the GeoCoder class.  [Check out this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197192/771999)

and

[Android Developer: GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)